# Make CSS Table Fill Parent Width and Keep Aspect Ratio for Height (email)

Tags: html, css, html-email, css-tables

I'm creating a HTML email with an image I need to overlay rectangular links on. Positioning is not supported by email clients, and image maps have resize issues and will have bad link placement on mobile clients. If anyone is aware of any other solution that will work with all major email clients, I'd be interested in knowing.

The solution I'm currently opting for is creating a table with a background image and using height/rowspan to place table cells where the links should be.

I want the width of the table to expand fill the container's width, but also have the height of the table expand to be a certain proportion of the table's width. Something like the following - :

```
<div id="container" style="width:100px">
    <!-- make this table have 100px height -->
    <table style="table-layout:fixed;width:100%;background:url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=')">
        <tr><td></td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I can't specify a fixed height for the container, as that is provided by the email client. The width is also different for different email clients.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Background images do not work in Outlook, some versions of Android, Gmail, Notes. - https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/color-background/background-image/

Comment: @gwally I believe there are workarounds to get background images to work on Outlook.

Comment: The workaround is to use VML for Outlook. I wanted to alert you to the fact there are a number of clients that do not work with background. Give us a better idea what you want to accomplish and maybe we can think of a way to pull it off.

Comment: @gwally Ultimately, all I want is to be able to take an image and add links to rectangular areas of that image. I want this image and the links to resize correctly for mobile email clients.

Comment: You could divide up the image into rectangles and wrap an href around each image. Use a table to keep the grid in one cohesive  image. Then you don't have to worry about clients that don't work with background images.

Comment: @gwally Thanks for your help. That's a last resort due to the development effort required in the system I'm working with. I'm hoping it doesn't come to that.